# Data Dictionary Creation for Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, dictionary, crystal-reports

I'm not too familiar with Crystal Reports or with Data Dictionary creations. So please bear with me!

But in sum, I want to create a data dictionary (consisting of typical - business definition, table name, schema, column, data type, etc.) for all of these Crystal Reports that I have.

Now, had all the Crystal Reports been written using Stored Procedures in our DB - this wouldn't be a question.  BUT - they are not and are straight up Queries copy/pasted into these Crystal reports.

I'm not entirely sure what would be the best way to extract the tables/columns being used in each of these reports and would be the best approach to try and document it.

Any insightful tips and tricks are greatly appreciated!

(FYI Using SQL Server)

Comment: couldn't understand what's your question is?  what problem you are facing with queries?

Comment: The problem that I'm encountering here is that users HAVE created a BUNCH of crystal reports just slapping in a full query (SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB.... FROM Table1...etc.) rather than create a SP.  This causes some problems for me because I want to create a Data Dictionary here - and I need to know what columns/tables are being used.  It appears I have to log into EACH Crystal report and view it rather than run a simple query if it was kept in a SP

Comment: Did you ever find an automated solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have to deal with the same thing in my office.  Yes, using SProcs would be much easier.  That's not an option where I work.  My team and I ended up getting rid of the Crystal Reports, and running everything using VBA for Access and Excel.  It takes a bit of effort to convert everything, but once it's up and running, it's much better than Crystal Reports.  Well, at least that's been our findings.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option for us :\ - we're using a third part vendor which almost exclusively works in BO items (WebI, Crystal, etc.)